# How to set topic by content in kafka consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, backend

I want to send different messages to kafka.
They are categorized by different topics.
However which topic it belongs to is set in the content of it.
For example, a message like this belongs to topic machine.

2021-7-21 machine 323 China Hangzhou

How can I control kafka to distribute to different topics while I can only know which topic to send until I get the message?

Answer (score 0):

Unclear where you "get the message", but you'll need that message before it can be sent and serialized, so get the topic name there

```
Producer<?, Message> p = new KafkaProducer<>(...)
Message m = ...

p.send(new ProducerRecord<>(m.getYourField(), m));
```

If you are getting messages from other Kafka topics, you can use KStreams `branch` to split apart the incoming data to different topologies/topics

Comment: In the example,,word 'machine' is in the message. Is there any code sample about KStreams branch?

Comment: Then parse your record text to get the topic name... Ideally, you should be using a structured format like JSON or Avro, and not plaintext (for example, any code that splits on spaces would break if you added any other word between the data and the "topic" field). And yes, in the Kafka Streams documentation, there is examples for all the methods